# ContextMenu bound to ObservableCollection<string> - show item if count == 0

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

I've got an observable collection of strings to thats data bound to my XAML contextmenu:

The ViewModel-Property:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Indexes
{
    get { return _Indexes; }
    private set
    {
        if (value != _Indexes)
        {
            _Indexes = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Indexes");
        }
    }
}
```

The XAML code:

```
<viewmodel:IndexViewModel x:Key="IndexViewModel" />

<ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenu_Index" Placement="Mouse" IsOpen="False">
    <ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <MenuItem Header="No items!" IsEnabled="False" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <MenuItem.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={StaticResource IndexViewModel}, Path=Indexes.Count}" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </MenuItem.Style>
            </MenuItem>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Path=Indexes, Source={StaticResource IndexViewModel}}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
    <ContextMenu.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContextMenu"></Style>
    </ContextMenu.Style>
    <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="string">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" MouseDown="TextBlock_Index_MouseDown"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
</ContextMenu>
```

Now I want to show the "No items" menu item if the count of Indexes is 0. But unfortunately it doesn't work this way, the "No items!" menu item is not shown. Do you have some hints?

Comment: what you mean by "doesn't work" ? error message or unexpected result?

Comment: Sorry, unexpected result. The "No items" menu template isn't shown

Comment: can you just return new [] {"No Item!"} from the property when _Indexes.Count == 0?

Comment: I had this idea already, but it's a little bit complex and there is no possibility to set a specific style (eg bold font, isenabled=false) to the menu item if you take this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [Dependency Property Setting Precedence List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#listing) and because of that when you manually set `Visibility` it has priority over style trigger. Bring default value as setter into your `Style` instead of setting it against `MenuItem` and then `Style.Trigger` will be able to change that value:

```
<MenuItem Header="No items!" IsEnabled="False">
   <MenuItem.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
         <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={StaticResource IndexViewModel}, Path=Indexes.Count}" Value="0">
               <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </MenuItem.Style>
</MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, displaying a `MenuItem` to say 'No items!' is unhelpful and incorrect... surely your users can tell when there are no `MenuItem`s without being told that. Even if you feel that you absolutely *do* have to do that, then why don't you simply add an *actual* item into your data bound collection?:

```
Indexes.Add("No items!");
```

In your `AddItem` method, you'd just need to check for the existence of this item before adding a new item:

```
if (Indexes.Contains("No items!")) Indexes.Remove("No items!");
Indexes.Add(newItem);
```

In your comment, you said that you couldn't `Style` this item differently... I don't know why you'd want to do that anyway, but you *could* just use the [`DataTemplateSelector` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do that for you. It would easier for you to implement your requirements this way.